How to set env variable based on /etc/hostname file in docker-compose
I want to set the value of hostname to some enviroment variable. When it is not defined I would like to read etc/hostname file and get a generated one? When I log into container to check what variables are there (printenv) a HOSTNAME is already defined. But in docker-compose a value of ${HOSTNAME} is empty. Should be the HOSTNAME available there?
docker-test:
    image: "docker/test"
    hostname: my_host_name
    environment:
      MY_HOSTNAME_ENV: ${HOSTNAME}

The solution could be just to use the same value for hostname and MY_HOSTNAME_ENV but in case of lack of hostname defined the value should be taken from /etc/hostname. How to do it?
I was trying to do something like this but does't work
MY_HOSTNAME_ENV: ${cat /etc/hostname}

Or maybe use a CMD in Dockerfile to do this and set a variable there?

Your question would benefit from a clearer distinction between environment variables on the host and in the container. Docker compose has access to environment variables on the host and sets variables inside the container. MY_HOSTNAME_ENV: ${HOSTNAME} means 'take the value of HOSTNAME on the host and set MY_HOSTNAME_ENV inside the container to that value'.

How is your application code using this value?  That file contains what the current environment thinks its own hostname is, but that's not necessarily an externally-accessible name.  Containers can't usually see this level of detail of the host's network environment in any case.
